# document.write will not print on browser window

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm working on Problem 4 from the Euler Project (Largest Palindrome Product - https://projecteuler.net/problem=4 ) and I need to test my code however document.write does not seem to wanna work. This is my first time posting a question on Stack Overflow so please tell me if I need to clarify or note any mistakes I make. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
//JS_RUNNER.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS_PROBLEMS.js"></script>
</html>

//JS_PROBLEMS.js
var l = 0;
for(var a = 100; a < 1000; a++) {
    for(var b = 100; b < 1000; b++) {
        var p = (a*b).toString();
        var t = "";
        for(var i = p.length; i >= 0; i--) {
            t += p[i];
            if(((a*b) > l) && (p.localeCompare(t) == 0) {
                l = a * b;
            }
        }
    }
}
document.write(l);
```

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis on the nested if statement. `if(((a*b) > l) && (p.localeCompare(t) == 0) {` should be `if(((a*b) > l) && (p.localeCompare(t) == 0)) {`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing bracket on your if()

```
//JS_PROBLEMS.js
var l = 0;
for(var a = 100; a < 1000; a++) {
    for(var b = 100; b < 1000; b++) {
        var p = (a*b).toString();
        var t = "";
        for(var i = p.length; i >= 0; i--) {
            t += p[i];
            if ( ( (a*b) > l) && (p.localeCompare(t) == 0) ) {//extra bracket needed here after the 0
                l = a * b;
            }
        }
    }
}
document.write(l);
```

As an added note, if you're testing Javascript in the browser, it's usually a good idea to have the developer tools open (F12 in most browsers will give you this).

using console.log(); will write data to the console and you'll also get error reports.

Comment: ahh i see thank you for the fix and the developer tool tip!

Comment: If you could accept the answer also, it would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Because there's an error here:

if(((a*b) > l) && (p.localeCompare(t) == 0)***)*** {

You didn't close the round bracket of if condition.

```
var l = 0;
for(var a = 100; a < 1000; a++) {
    for(var b = 100; b < 1000; b++) {
        var p = (a*b).toString();
        var t = "";
        for(var i = p.length; i >= 0; i--) {
            t += p[i];
            if(((a*b) > l) && (p.localeCompare(t) == 0)) {
                l = a * b;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this one.

```
var largePalin = 0;
var intA=0;
var intB = 0;
for(var a = 100; a < 1000; a++) {
    for(var b = 100; b < 1000; b++) {
        var strNumber = (a*b).toString();
         if(strNumber===strNumber.split("").reverse().join("")){
               // document.writeln(strNumber)

                if(strNumber > largePalin){
                    intA = a;
                    intB=b;
                    largePalin = strNumber;
                }
         } 
    }
}
document.writeln("Largest palindrome product is (a,b) ====== ("+intA+" , "+intB+")" )
document.write(largePalin)
```

Comment: oh i was unaware of a reverse() method existing, thank you!